# 'UITableViewCell' not showing label

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This is my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];}

    self.credits = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    self.credits.text = @"Available Credits";
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.credits.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.credits];
```

credits is the label here

Comment: is your self.credits nil ?

Comment: can you show `self.credits`

Comment: Where do you create the `UILabel` respectively where is tag 101 assigned to the label?

Comment: Credits is the outlet defined in .h file of this TableViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You store a cell label in your `UIViewController` and then try to `addSubview` in the content view.

The right approach for this should be:

1. Create a subclass of `UITableViewCell`
2. Assign a label inside this cell as a property (could be by code, by xib)
3. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` use that property name to assign `Available Credits`

Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should look like this in the end:

```
- (MyCustomUITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCustomUITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    self.myNewProperty.text = @"Available Credits";
}
```